# I have MFC 32 bit application, i want run it on 64 machine with MFC shared libraries

Tags: mfc

I tried to run the mentioned application configuration. But it is showing the error " side by side configuration is missing"
Is there any way i can run the 32 MFC application on 64 bit machine?

Comment: 32-bit apps run fine on 64-bit Windows. But if you linked MFC dynamically, your app needs the VC++ redistributable DLLs in order to run. Which ones and how to deploy them depends on the Visual Studio version that you used to build the app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using VS2008 development environment

Comment: You need to install the 32-bit versions of the redistributable(s), although you are on a 64-bit OS. 32-bit applications can load 32-bit dlls only.

Comment: @dxiv thanks for your reply, we can't install  VC++ 2008 redistributable x86 on client machine, So any other solution?

Comment: @GanpatLabde Then you'll have to either link the runtimes statically, or copy the DLLs next to your .exe a.k.a. "app-local deployment".

Comment: Did you consider compiling your application as 64 bit application? It's not that hard.

Comment: That doesn't change a thing. If the OP is unable to install the redistributables on the target machine, they are going to have to manually ship their dependencies anyway. The process is identical for 32-bit and 64-bit applications.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for the suggestion. But i have only 32 bit application specific requirement and 32 bit application work for both architecture 32 and 64 bit.